# Why loop doubled the items add in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

someclass_adapterEvents_part got 20 items. After the loop ends GlobalData.buffer got 40 and someclass_adapter got 40 and i'm really confused! Both someclass_adapter and GlobalData.buffer are empty before loop.

```
SomeClass tmp_sc;
for (int i = 0; i < events_part.size(); i++)
{
    tmp_sc = events_part.get(i);
    someclass_adapter.add(tmp_sc);
    GlobalData.buffer.add(tmp_sc);
}
```

someclass_adaper is adapter that extend ArrayAdapter(SomeClass)
and buffer is static ArrayList(SomeClass). Its in java, in specially android code.
I used Global.buffer to initzialized someclass_adapter like

```
someclass_adapter = new SomeClassAdapter(this, R.layout.lv_events_item, GlobalData.buffer);
```

Comment: Print the sizes before and after the loop. Are you sure GlobalData.buffer is empty before this loop?

Comment: You need to clear the `ArrayList` after adding the items and check by printing the logs the size of your both arraylist before adding items and after adding items

Comment: Do a check like this: `if(someclass_adapter==GlobalData.buffer) { System.out.println("They are the same");}` to see if the two are the same... It might happen that you are referencing **the same collection** through two **different names**...

Comment: I edited my post. Both someclass_adapter and GlobalData.buffer are empty before loop.

Comment: Both empty, but are they both the same collection

Comment: print the size of event_part.size() before the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your someclass_adapter is wrapping the buffer instance. So essentially you are adding same elements twice to the same ArrayList. It will be enough to add them to adapter only.

Comment: I use static GlobalData.buffer to cache data when activity recreate. GlobalData.buffer is used in someclass_adapter when init and for getView method of someclass_adapter. I thought there is no pass by reference in java, so when i pass GlobalData.buffer to someclass_adapter's constructor i expect someclass_adapter to copy  GlobalData.buffer in its inner ArrayList.